# xtext injected parser

Tags: xtext

```
@Inject
protected void setInjectedParser(IParser parser) {
    this.parser = parser;
}
```

I want to manually run the xtext engine and i'm not sure when and where the setInjectedParser is being called.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Guice will call the #setInjectedParser(IParser) while constructing an instance of XtextResource to inject it somewhere else. This is done by Guice because the setter is annotated with @Inject.

> manually run the xtext engine

What do you mean by this?

Comment: until now i used the 'launch runtime eclipse' to run the xtext as plugin.
now i want to use some of it's method in external application which will do it in command line and not eclipse plugin

Comment: In general I have my dsl as plugin and I want to create a new app that use my dsl. so i tried to write this code:                          
JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
IParseResult r = p.parse(new StringReader("{}")); 
//once that work it will be the file data instead of {}
        but when i do the parse the node model builder is null and the following line has exception:return doParse(ruleName, in, nodeModelBuilder.get(), 0);
and i'm not sure how to init nodeModelBuilder
i'm sure i missing some steps but i'm not quite familiar with the xtext process.